# How to use getDocumentElement in user-defined class?

Tags: java, xml, interface

I am implementing a class that reads XML files and calls methods related to the tags. I have coded this in C++ and all I had to do was inherit something like wxXmlDocument inorder to get the root of my Xml.

I want to do this in Java, and the class that can get me the root element is the interface Document. I want to be able to call getDocumentElement() without having to implement it. Can anyone tell me how?

Thanks. :)

Comment: I want to be able to use the getDocumentElement() method in my class. How will I achieve that?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the DOM parsing built into the JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest example of using the built-in DOM parser:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename));
```

Note that the DOM version of parsing will load the entire document into memory. If you are dealing with very large documents *(compared to main heap available)* you will likely want to learn how to use the SAX or STAX versions of parsing.

Comment: But my myDocument class has a IS-A relationship with Document. What do I do about that?

Comment: Have you thought about using your class as a wrapper around the `Document` provided by the library instead of trying to re-invent the wheel here?

Comment: I did try that, however the code that I am porting uses a IS-A relationship with an XMLDocument class.